# Master to Slave Replication pausing

Tags: mysql, replication

I would like to get insights from everyone here in this community. After we apply indexes on our Tables on Database. If some users generate big reports. Replication suddenly stopped and what we are doing to run again the replication is to restart the mysqld in Slave.

Any recommendation is highly appreciated.

Comment: No need to say everything twice. No need to say everything twice.

Comment: Assume that reports were generated on the replica server. Probably you are using not-transactional engines so when the replication tries to apply changes from the master, it has to wait until some sqls are finished. 
My recommendations is to analyze indexes (they are correctly build or new needed) and optimize the queries for this big reports.